# PHP-FPM Workers messing up php.ini loading?

Tags: ubuntu, php, php-fpm

I installed PHP 5.3.8 from source on Ubuntu Natty. I also enabled FPM during configuration.

However, I've been having issues installing PHP extensions. When I add the extension to my php.ini file (e.g. `extension=apc.so`) and restart PHP (i.e. `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`), I get an error like the one below:

```
Starting php-fpm PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'apc' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'geoip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'geoip' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
```

My PHP-FPM conf is has the setting `pm.start_servers = 5`, so I have about 5 PHP-FPM workers active. Are they all trying to load the php.ini file when I restart PHP (hence the message that the module has already been loaded)?! If they are, is there a way I can prevent that to stop the errors as it the errors become fatal when I load Zend Loader?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuration Issues with PECL and PHP-FPM](http://serverfault.com/questions/331265/configuration-issues-with-pecl-and-php-fpm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this earlier on StackOverflow. Here's the link to the information.

[Does each PHP-FPM Worker individually load php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173959/does-each-php-fpm-worker-individually-load-php-ini)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The following command shows you which .ini-files are used:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/apc.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/memcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/xhprof.ini
```

This should help you trouble-shooting.

Most of the time you want to not edit `php.ini` directly, but instead override/extend the configuration by placing additional .ini-files in a directory (`/usr/local/etc/php` in my example).

If this is not set/available, you need to adjust your `./configure` command to include `--with-config-file-scan-dir`.

Btw, [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) might be a better option for you.

Comment: Hi Till, sorry for the late response. I was able to solve this issue earlier. I've posted a link to my answer. Cheers.